# Getting error again and again while using "ids" in kv file

Tags: python, kivy, twisted

well, I am getting a problem when using "ids" in kivy.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver

class User(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write("hey brother")

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print (data)

class ChatClientFActory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol=User

    def __init__(self,app):
        self.app=app

class ClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return User()

def run():
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost",8000,ClientFactory())
    reactor.run()


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager

Builder.load_file("chat.kv")
Builder.load_file("chat2.kv")

class User1(Screen):
    pass
class User2(Screen):
    pass

s=ScreenManager()
s.add_widget(User1(name="start"))
s.add_widget(User2(name="let's_chat"))

class ChatApp(App):
    def connect(self):
        print(self.root.ids.message.text)
        self.parent.current="let's_chat"

    def build(self):
        return s

if __name__=="__main__":
    ChatApp().run()
```

when I use "self.root.ids.message.text", it always shows that " 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**' " . I searched many times but got no solution. Below is the kv file of this:-

```
<User1>:
    RelativeLayout:
        TextInput:
            text:
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
            size_hint: .3, .2
        Button:
            text:"start"
            pos_hint:{"x":0,"bottom":0}
            size_hint: .3, .2
            on_press:
                app.connect()
```

Please help.

Comment: I have added "id: message", below TextInput, But still having the same error

Comment: maybe you should init some attributes in your class `ChatApp` by implementing an `__init__(self):` constructor and call `super(ChatApp, self).__init__()` inside

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it didn't worked.

Comment: ScreenManager is not the parent of ChatApp. I would extend ScreenManager and then work from there with ids or/ and Stringproperties. Alternatively, add s as an Objectproperty to ChatApp and work from there. Your referencing is just not pointing to the ScreenManager or a Screen.

Comment: or maybe you can pass `id=sm` `(ScreenManager(id=sm))` when creating Screenmanager and then do sth like `self.ids.sm.ids.message.text` and `self.ids.sm.current = "let's chat"`

Comment: IMO, it is best to avoid using id/ids in your app altogether. It's best to become comfortable with kivy properties, especially ObjectProperty, to access attributes and values. It's worth the time to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScreenManager is not the parent of ChatApp. You need to find a way of referencing your widgets correctly. This is a sketch of a possible solution. Although not tested! Alternatively, try extending ScreenManager and work your way from there with StringProperty, ObjectProperty and ids. Hope it helps although not tested. If you have a standalone example without `twisted` I could help you better and test my solution.

python

```
class ChatApp(App):
    sm = ObjectProperty()
    screen1 = ObjectProperty()
    screen2 = ObjectProperty()

    def connect(self):
        print(self.screen1.ids.txtinpt.text)
        self.sm.current="let's_chat"

    def build(self):
        self.sm=ScreenManager()
        self.screen1 = User1(name="start")
        self.screen2 = User2(name="let's_chat")
        self.sm.add_widget(self.screen1)
        self.sm.add_widget(self.screen2)
        return self.sm
```

kv

```
<User1>:
    RelativeLayout:
        TextInput:
            id: txtinpt
            pos_hint:{"center_x":.5,"center_y":.5}
            size_hint: .3, .2
```

Comment: It worked like a charm thanx, but the TexInput box became un-clickable, but i will solve it.  Thanx

Comment: Hi @akashtyagi if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.Also, if you like sth you can upvote it. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: sorry @PalimPalim i am new to stackoverflow, so i didn't knew that. I upvoted it and checked it, and thanx again for the solution

Comment: @Palimapalim I got the same error again, when i tried your code again in a new file, its not working now. please help

Comment: Can you a reduced form of your app, just the kivy, so that I can try it myself. TextInput could be disabled if you specify it. Other possibility is that the twister thing is blocking the main thread and you might need to look into threading. For example if you use the sleep function from the time module a kivy GUI will freeze until the execution of this function is over.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole progran without twisted its very simple but i am having difficulty in calling method from a kv button.

Chat.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, ObjectProperty

Builder.load_file("chat.kv")
Builder.load_file("chat2.kv")


class User1(Screen):
    pass

class User2(Screen):
    pass


class ChatApp(App):
    sm = ObjectProperty()
    screen1 = ObjectProperty()
    screen2 = ObjectProperty()

    def connect(self):
        print(self.screen1.ids.txtinpt.text)

    def build(self):
        self.sm=ScreenManager()
        self.screen1 = User1(name="start")
        self.screen2 = User2(name="chat_screen")
        self.sm.add_widget(self.screen1)
        self.sm.add_widget(self.screen2)
        return self.sm






if __name__=="__main__":
    ChatApp().run()
```

chat.kv

```
<User1>:
    RelativeLayout:
        TextInput:
            id:Username
            pos_hint:{"center_x": .5, "center_y": .7}
            size_hint: .3, .2
        TextInput:
            id:Password
            pos_hint:{"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
            size_hint: .3, .2
        Button:
            text:"send"
            pos_hint:{"center_x": .5, "center_y": .3}
            size_hint: .3, .2
            on_press:
                root.manager.current="chat_screen"
```

chat2.kv

```
<User2>:
    RelativeLayout:
        Label:
            id:show_msg
            text:""
            pos_hint:{"x":0,"top":1}
            size_hint_x: root.width
            size_hint_y: .5
        TextInput:
            id:txt_msg
            pos_hint:{"x": 0, "bottom": 0}
            size_hint: .6, .2
            multiline:False
        Button:
            text:"send_msg"
            pos_hint:{"x": .7, "bottom": 0}
            size_hint: .3, .2
            on_press:
                app.connect()
```

its showing error:

```
File "/root/PycharmProjects/Chat/chat2.kv", line 19, in <module>
     app.connect()
   File "/root/PycharmProjects/Chat/Chat.py", line 23, in connect
     print(self.screen1.ids.txtinpt.text)
   File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 839, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__ (/tmp/pip-build-0vou9szt/kivy/kivy/properties.c:12654)
 AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'
```

Sorry if i did something stupid. I think i am having difficulty in using app method to call any function. If yes then please tell me how to use "self.app".

Comment: there was a small referencing error. If you update your connect method to     `def connect(self):
        print(self.screen2.ids.txt_msg.text)`
it works just fine.

Comment: i changed from screen1 to screen2 and the id to txt_msg, because you named it like that in the kv file

Comment: feeling bad, that i made such little mistakes. By the way thankyou.

Comment: now worries, it is always the little things I get stuck at as well. if your question was solved you could accept an answer, but up to you. (Activating check mark next to up or down vote button on the answer). Or did you unaccept the answer on purpose?